# Control Value Accessor in simple terms

Tags: angular

What is Angular's Control Value Accessor

I've tried @input, @output approach, but that gets complicated during validations and specially for ngModel

Expect a wrapper component that houses a 3rd party UI control to work with ease

Comment: https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor

Answer (score 1):

Alright Control Value Accessor in simple terms:
**Purpose**: To have a custom UI child component that is a wrapper that uses a third party UI widget maybe like PrimeNg, ngx-bootstrap's DatePicker. The wrapper can easily sync with the Form control(Parent component) without having to use @Inputs/Outputs. Mainly, how would you otherwise notify the parent about a validaiton. Easily through CVA.

Example: 
Imagine you want to build a datepicker from ngx-bootstrap like so:
Lets assume you have a form that uses your custom DatePicker:

Form.ts:

```
currentDate: Date = new Date();
onDateChanged($event){
  // do something with the received date..Maybe call an api for the selectedDate's data
}
```

Form.html:

```
<custom-date-picker id="selectedDate" name="fieldName" [(ngModel)]="currentDate" (onDateChanged)="onDateChanged($event)"></custom-date-picker>
```

Create a wrapper component:
CustomDatePicker.ts:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'custom-date-picker',
  templateUrl: 'custom-date-picker.component.html',
  providers: [
    {
      provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR,
      useExisting: forwardRef(() => IpxDatePickerComponent),
      multi: true
    }
  ]
})

export class CustomDatePickerComponent implements ControlValueAccessor {
   onChanged: any = () => {};
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty
  onTouched: any = () => {};

  writeValue(obj: any): void {
    if (obj) {
      this.selectDate(obj);
    }
  }
  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChanged = fn;
  }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouched = fn;
  }
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-empty
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {}

  selectDate(val): void {
    this.selectedDate = val;
  }

  dateChanged = (e: Date): void => {
    if (e) {
      this.onChanged(e);// this statement should have ideally set your parent forms ngModel variable to the new selected date.
      this.onDateChanged.emit(e);
    }
  };
}
```

CustomDatePicker.html:

```
 <input type="text" #datePicker="bsDatepicker" placeholder="Datepicker"  (bsValueChange)="dateChanged($event)" [(ngModel)]="selectedDate" [bsConfig]="bsConfig" />
```

Thats it,, now if you see, the ngModel of your form will be in sync. And also the child and parent controls will be in sync with the selectedDate along with validations like touched etc.

I actually found this methodology useful, because, I found a lot of syncing issues while implementing using the regular @inputs, @outputs.

We could even now with CVA use them, but they'll be mostly for manipulating other data rather than the wrappers purpose(date in this case)

Comment: Maybe you should review your definition of `simple terms` 

Comment: Also, the purpose is not to encapsulate a third party library, it is one of the possible uses for it. Control value accessors are much more than that !

Comment: @Sri, in your code, it's not `this.onDateChanged(e)`?

Comment: @Maryannah appreciate your feedback. Would you be able to let know of any more strong use cases that cannot be easily achieved using the basic flow? My use case was to wrap a ui widget. Hence the explanation.

Comment: @Sri create a typeahead from scratch, create a custom select tag where you can control the display of options, allow a user to edit directly the content of an HTML element, synchronise the control with an API ... The possibilities are endless really !

Comment: Aah right.. Many use cases to think about. Yes, I  Saw a lecture in a conf where a typeahead was built.

Answer (score 0):

In simple terms, a `ControlValueAccessor` is a way of adding `ngModel`/`formControl` to **any HTML element** instead of just form controls.

It relies on just a few methods, which are all explained in [the documentation](https://angular.io/api/forms/ControlValueAccessor).

For instance, you can group several controls into one, or create an input with a `contenteditable` on a `<p>` element.